# jQuery .focusout() also when .keyup() occurs in Firefox 33.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I release a key in an input form html field, I get in Firefox 33.1 in jQuery an keyup event and also an unwanted focusout event. I just want the keyup event when releasing the key.

This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="libraries/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="contact_form">
            <input class="contact_save" type="text" value="" />
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function($){
            $('#contact_form .contact_save').focusout(function() {
                alert("focusout!");
            });
            $('#contact_form .contact_save').keyup(function() {
                alert("keyup!");
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Michael

Comment: Is it because you're removing focus due to the alert?

Comment: You get focusout due to the alert you got, http://jsfiddle.net/yqo1zyec/ open the console and you can see there is no focusout on keyup

Comment: @dav_i Yes. See your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the alert causes the focusout to be called. Putting the result in another element for an example does not cause it to trigger:

```js
$('#contact_form .contact_save').focusout(function() {
  alert("focusout!");
});
$('#contact_form .contact_save').keyup(function() {
  $('#result').val('keyup');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="contact_form">
  <input class="contact_save" type="text" value="" />
  <output id="result" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying using:

```
$('#contact_form .contact_save').blur(function() {
    alert("focusout!");
});
```